How to deal with conflicting dependencies/versions?
I am developing an application that offers an api to develop plugins for this application. Each plugin can have other plugins as dependencies.
I am planning to offer some basic plugins out of the box, like storing and organizing files into folders, providing fonts and support for ui themes.
However I stumbled across the following problem while thinking of the implementation:
Lets say we have the plugins A v1.0 and B v1.0 that both depend on C v1.0. Now B gets a major update to v2.0 and now depends on C v2.0, but plugin A still depends on C v1.0 as it has not been updated yet. Now C cannot be upgraded from v1.0 to v2.0 in the application because A does not support v2.0. This means that a plugin cannot be upgraded as long as there are plugins that depend on an older version. So a third party plugin that has not been updated forever and depends on an old version of C blocks every other plugin from upgrading.
This could be solved by having multiple versions of the plugins installed. So there is not either C v1.0 or C v2.0 installed but both. Each plugin uses the correct version of its dependencies.
However, this is not a solution for my application. Lets say I have a low level plugin that offers file storage. Having multiple versions of that plugin active works as long as they manage these files together which would not be a problem. But lets say a major version of this plugin introduces a new breaking change file format, now there is no way two different versions could work simultaneously.
Am I overthinking this? Or am I missing something obvious? How do applications like VSCode or basically any application that offers plugins with other plugins as dependencies?

This is a really difficult problem any package manager has to address – solving version constraints is often an NP-complete problem. Many plugin systems don't even support explicit dependency tracking, and leave it up to users to notice conflicts. Or if they support side-by-side versions, they might assume that this is always safe. Here, you might want to think about how to offer plugin APIs that are highly stable (e.g. limit interaction between plugins), and how to facilitate rapid updates in the plugin ecosystem (e.g. requiring them to be Open Source so that they can be forked if necessary).

There is no easy solution here. If an incompatible version of a library/library is released, there is little you can do using technology. But I find that kind of situation unlikely.
If a plugin or library is popular, releasing new, incompatible version will result in one of two situations happening.
Either the new version is really good and whole ecosystem quickly migrates to the new version. Those that use old version will be abandoned by it's users and new alternatives will be developed for the new version.
Other option is that new version is bad and the ecosystem ignores it, remaining on previous version.
It is up to the original library/plugin's creator to decide if this kind of risk is acceptable to revamp the library, or if it is better to maintain backwards compatibility.
So while your problem is possible, in practice communities and ecosystems are self-correcting in case of these kind of dependency issues. And there is little you can help using technology.

It is worth noting that Maven, NPM, APT,  and all other package managers have invented some kind of conflict resolution policies based on version ranges. I would look into existing implementations (or at least ideas) before rolling out your own.

@Basilevs All of those are about detecting conflict, not resolving. None of those can solve the issue, if there isn't a valid dependency chain. Which is what I believe OP is asking about.

they resolve conflict that would happen if dependency required exact version match. Meanwhile, semver, for example, requires only major to match, and minor to be in a range.

@Basilevs The whole point of the question is that the valid dependency chain DOES NOT EXIST. Even if you say that A is fine with versions 1.x.x of C and B is fine with 2.x.x of C, if your project references both A and B, there is no way to select valid version of C. What OP is asking if there is any technical way to make it possible to resolve this dependency issue.

Different versions of a component are often backward compatible to an extent. So B v2.0 could depend on C v1.2, which is compatible with A even if rigid dependency resolution protocol indicates otherwise.

A new version of a library which is incompatible to persisted files of prior versions is likely to run into the case this answer describes as "bad and the ecosystem ignores it".

User facing plugins should not use other plugins as common dependencies. They may share a common library (which is neither a stand-alone plugin nor user-facing). Still new libraries must be backwards compatible, especially when it comes to file persistence (otherwise noone who has saved older files will ever migrate to a newer version).
If C was a library, A1.0 could easily be bundled and used with C1.0, and B2.0 could be bundled and used with C2.0, both at the same time. A1.0 works with all file formats provided by C1.0. B works with all the file formats provided by C2.0, which should be a superset of all the formats offered by C1.0.
Of course, when A1.0 tries to process data in an incompatible format created by B2.0 (using C2.0), then A has an implicit dependency on B and needs to updated sooner or later as well. But this has nothing to do with plugins, that's a standard issue with all kinds of software, versions and file formats, and it cannot be addressed by a plugin mechanics.

Why should plugins not have other plugins as dependencies? That means that every common functionality that may be required by multiple plugins have to be implemented in the core system which kind of goes against the plugin architecture. With plugins being able to depend on other plugins you can keep the core as small as possible which is one of the key points of a plugin architecture. There are plugins architectures that do allow this, eg vscode or eclipse (though vscode does not allow to depend on a specific version, it always uses the latest)

@AzusDkk: lets says a user-facing plugin C is installed in version 1.0. Then installing C2.0 by some plugin manager will usually mean to upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0, hence replacing the installation. But if your plugin C is separated into a user-facing part and a library, lets call it "Clib", then C1.0 can use Clib1.0, Clib2.0 can use C2.0, A1.0 can use Clib1.0, B2.0 can use Clib2.0, all at the same time. You decouple the plugin-installation / upgrade procedure from the dependency of the plugin components that way.

... alternatively, when one does not split C into a reusable part and a user-facing part, and let other plugins decide to use always "the latest and the greatest". C needs to stay highly backwards compatible with each new version. When B2.0 forces an upgrade of C from 1.0 to 2.0, breaking changes in C are an absolute no-go for not breaking compatibility with A1.0.

the separation of the "library" and the ui decouples the plugins, however A1.0 can use Clib1.0, B2.0 can use Clib2.0, all at the same time is unfortunately not an option for me. As I stated multiple versions in parallel does not work for some cases. To take up the example with storing files: of course the new version should be compatible with files stored in an older format, but the older version will never be compatible with the new format. Thus running multiple versions in parallel might work for some cases, but not always.

@AzusDkk: yes, and that's exactly what I wrote in my answer (and it has nothing to do with plugins specificially). Still, moving the reusable part of a plugin into a lib allows you to shift the control which version is required and installed from a "plugin manager UI" into the components A, B, and C which actually use them. That does not resolve all compatibility problems, but a lot.

I think I unterstand now. Because every client facing part of a plugin is bundled and shipped with the plugin libraries it depends on, there is no direct dependency between client facing plugins which makes the installation/upgrading process much simpler. Is that correct? However I am not sure if this offers a good ui/ux, because as soon as you upgrade a plugin there may be the chance that things just start to break out of nowhere because of conflicting versions.@Euphoric approach offers a better ui in my opinion. Restricting the user from upgrading until all dependencies support the newer...

... version is still not amazing, but at least the chance of things starting to break randomly is smaller (hopefully). Of course shipping the client facing side and the library seperately is still possible with this approach, but the libraries should be stored somewhere central and not shipped with each client side.

@AzusDkk: "as soon as you upgrade a plugin there may be the chance that things just start to break out of nowhere" - that is what will happen most likely when only one version of each library can be installed. libraries should be stored somewhere central - well, that is what caused DLL hell under Windows in the past - the misguided idea of saving a few kb disk space by centralizing libs. One can avoid this either by having a rigid versioning management system for libs, or, simpler, by accepting that duplicate libs is not as bad as it seems to be at a first glance.

I dont exactly get why having duplicate libs would be better than only one version. If there can be multiple versions of the same library we are probably gonna run into compatibility issues between those versions if they share file storage or else. If there is only one version this issue will never be faced and if you only let a user upgrade if every plugin that depends on this library supports the newer version then there will never be the chance that things may break because of conflicts. Maybe you could explain why you think things start to break if there is only one version installed.

There are some policies regarding backwards compatibility that you can force  upon your plugin writers:

Not breaking the signature of public types, methods and properties.

When a method or type is published, the plugin writer must maintain this type/method in future versions. Any changes that would break other extensions that use the older version are forbidden or require a process of first declaring the method/type obsolete.
The policy would forbid removing the type or method.
Depending on the runtime of your system you can allow the extension writers to add optional parameters, to make ignored parameters optional, to add overloads of methods.


For datastructures –i.e. plugins could communicate via structures exchanged via APIs– you can adopt the principles used in google's protobuf definitions. We can apply these principles beyond protobuf and adapt them to create backwards and forwards compatible versions:

Do not add a required field (or parameter to methods and functions)
Clients written for the old version do not know about these fields and would break. Optional fields are ok to add, clients of the old version ignore them.
Do not change the type of a field (and of a parameter and returned value)
Obvious. However, –should you choose to apply the principles to something other than protobuf– your plugin writers might be allowed to upgrade a parameter to a more general type and upgrade a returned value to a more specific type; this depends on your runtime. And care and understanding is required.
Do Reserve Tag Numbers for Deleted Fields
Tag numbers are specific to protobuf, but the same applies for CSV and memory mapped messages: skip the space the removed fields occupied.
The guide continues with "You can also reserve names to avoid recycling now-deleted value names: reserved FOO, BAR;." this is wise. For key-value oriented formats reserving previously used keys and not recycling them is crucial for backwards and forwards compatibly.
Never Rely on Serialization Stability Across Builds
Worth mentioning; also beyond protobuf. I've seen lots of problems occur because of clients relying on things that should have been implementation details; for example: the order in which fields in JSON are serialized, undocumented methods, (undocumented) side-effects of methods, and order in which code is executed. Forcing the clients of plugins to only interact via the published interface prevents many version compatibility problems.
(As a developer, I would be grateful though if my development version of my Extension_A would be allowed to use unpublished features of my development version of my Extension_B; and if QA could test them both together before publishing.)



Systems like Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central and Saleforce take a similar approach on their landscape of extensions; but your project might not have the leverage to force this and a have others still take the effort to write plugins.
And of course, nothing prevents the team behind popular plugin MyPlugin-1.2.3 to do a complete and incompatible rewrite: MyPlugin2-0.6.0.
